# Ubuntu 14.04 does not connect to wireless

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, broadcom

I have a Sony Vaio  model SVF14A15CXB running Ubuntu 14.04 (just upgraded). Happily, my root is back, but currently, I am only able to connect with ethernet. I wasn't been able to connect at the library last night My Software and Updates GUI shows my `BCM43142 802.11b/g/n Broadcom 802.11` Linux STA wireless driver source from `bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)` is using an alternative driver.

[image: Screenshot showing broadcom wifi adapter]

Below I will supply some command line information, showing that my OS is not detecting wlan0 but only eth0.  How can I install the driver, load it, or do whatever I have to do so that wireless connections appear in the upper right hand corner of my Gnome panel so it is possible for me to go to Starbucks or the library and connect to wireless netowrks?  Currently I can do no such thing.

[image: Comcast wireless connection does not appear]

Comment: I'm sorry.  I failed to supply the command line I promised.  Here it is:

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7424939/

Comment: I guess what I need to do is create a wlan0 interface, because no such animal exists as output from iwconfig or ifconfig

Comment: Have you tried connecting with the ethernet cable disconnected? It will automatically connect by ethernet as long as you have the cable connected.

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: http://kayve.net/plug_out.png

Comment: http://kayve.net/plug_in.png

Answer (score 1):

I have a Sony Vaio and struggled for a long time to get the Wifi to work with Ubuntu 14.04 (something to do with the Wifi card and the kernel possibly?). I did a clean install of Ubuntu 14.10, with third party software and updates ticked during install and it now works perfectly.

Comment: This is not a decent answer.  If you explain the b and c and d it'll makes sense how you got from a to e.

Comment: If using 14.10 vs 14.04 works then this is a decent answer @Virusboy

Comment: @Seth I disagree.  There are a number of Sony Vaios around all with different hardware built-in.  @LittlePixie: Please [edit] your answer, give the model number of your particular Vaio and add the output of `lsusb` and *then* it becomes an *excellent* answer!  **;-)**

Comment: @fabby That does not make this any less of an answer, albeit a low quality one.

Comment: whoops shouldn't do the close vote queue when I'm tired...

Answer (score 0):

did you ignore the "let 3rd party software install" during the installation, it needs that to install wi-fi drivers, it said. If you did it after you might have the wrong ones. I know this isn't an answer but I think it can shed some light on the problem

Comment: http://kayve.net/no_Wifi.png

Comment: http://kayve.net/new_update.png

Comment: http://kayve.net/new_useless_app.png

Comment: I am even more scr*@&$#d now.  I have been evicted, so I am at a library now where I cannot get internet via ethernet.  I have to run a Windoze machine and transfer files via my external USB hard drive.  Here is a new screenshot

Comment: http://www.monkeyview.net/id/965/fsck/broadcom/BCM.vhtml

Comment: http://www.monkeyview.net/id/965/fsck/broadcom/SMBus01.vhtml

Comment: those screenshots are of viewing HTML created by the lshw command.  It created red text for hardware with something wrong with it.  I used lshw -html command and redirected to a file that I then viewed with a browser

Answer (score 0):

try to restart the network manager application
run

```
nm-applet
```

or

```
nm-applet&
```

if you want to run it in background .

come back to say how that went .

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7439023/

Comment: 0400000-c0403fff
root@kayve-VIAO:~# nm-applet&
[1] 12508
root@kayve-VIAO:~# nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon

Comment: I am pretty sure it is something related , I had the same with last version of lubuntu and it sorted out when I added the nm-applet to the startup application . Do updates and such I think everything is good except you cannot access wifi from gui .

Comment: with nmcli dev wifi connect <name> password <password>
you can set up from terminal , I think if you look in the 
network manager manual you will find a way out .
I realise that not having wifi can be a deal breaker